# Hausdorff space and compact subspaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be Hausdorff and $A,B \subseteq X$ be disjoint compact subspaces of $X$. Prove that there are $U$ and $V$ open disjoint sets in $X$, $A\subseteq U$ and $B\subseteq V$.

I know that: $A$ and $B$ are closed in $X$.

But I have no idea how to prove statement using that $X$ is Hausdorff since with that information I know what to do only with points :/

Maybe just an idea?

Comment: The statement that a compact set is closed, can be made stronger: A compact subset $A$ and a point $x\notin A$ have disjoint neighborhoods. Try to prove that first.

Comment: Done that. =)
My try is this: We first do that for every point in $A$ and set $B$. Union of that neighbourhoods (we take open neighbourhoods) is cover of $A$ and then there is finite subcover- we take $U$ is union of elements of that subcover. And for $V$ we take intersection of matching neighbourhoods of $B$, (and matching means that neighbourhoods we got when we used this statement for point from that finite  subset and set $B$).

Comment: Surely you meant to assume that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

Comment: Well done! A simple formula is: *Compact subsets behave like points*. Here they resemble the property of two points being separable by disjoint neighborhoods.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: It must be =)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disjoint compact sets in a Hausdorff space can be separated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18192/disjoint-compact-sets-in-a-hausdorff-space-can-be-separated)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix $a \in A$.  For every $x \in B$, we can find disjoint neighborhoods $U_x(a)$ of $a$ and $V_x(a)$ of $x$.  Since $B$ is compact, the open cover $\{V_x(a) : x \in B\}$ has a finite subcover $\{V_{x_1}(a) , \dots, V_{x_n}(a)\}$.  Let 
$V(a) = \bigcup_{i = 1}^n V_{x_i}(a)$ and $ U(a) = \bigcap_{i=1}^n U_{x_i}(a)$

Then $U(a)$ and $V(a)$ are disjoint neighborhoods of $a$ and $B$. The open cover $\{U(a) : a \in A\}$ of $A$ has a finite subcover $\{U(a_1), \dots, U(a_k\}$.  Let

$$U = \bigcup_{i = 1}^k U(a_i)$$
$$V = \bigcap_{i = 1}^k V(a_i)$$

It follows that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint neighborhoods of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: That's what I thought also (written in comment above =)) Thank you

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

1. Fix $b\in B$ use the Hausdorff property on the elements of $A$ and compactness of $A$ to construct construct $U_b,V_b$ such that 
   $$A\subset U_b,\qquad b\in V_b, \qquad U_b\cap V_b=\emptyset$$
2. Now $$\bigcap_{b\in B} U_b\supset A$$ 
   but $\bigcap_{b\in B} U_b$ need not be open, because it might not be a finite intersection.
   Finish off using compactness of $B$.