# Is $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}X_i$ nonempty and connected?

Tags: general-topology

In this post: [Understanding a proof about nested nonempty connected compact subsets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631126/understanding-a-proof-about-nested-nonempty-connected-compact-subsets) they threat the case when every connected subspace is also closed and $X$ is compact.

Is there any related proof about general non compact and non closed connected subsets?

If not are there any counter examples available? I mean a nested sequence of nonempty connected subset such that the intersection is not connected. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A more interesting question would be to require closedness and compactness but not Hausdorff property. See [Arbitrary intersection of closed, connected subsets of a compact space connected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29231/arbitrary-intersection-of-closed-connected-subsets-of-a-compact-space-connected)

Comment: But Arturo's counterexample solved your problem. Yes, $X$ needs not to be compact, but we can have a counterexample where $X$ is compact

Comment: Yeah, Im reading it. Thank you.

Comment: For non compact $X$, the second answer in my link solve your problem

Comment: should I delete this, then?

Comment: You can flag it as a duplicate. No need for deletion. (as this is not an exact duplicate; keeping it would be conducive to searching)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier counter-example would be taking

$$X_i=\Bbb R^2\setminus\left(R_i\times\{0\}\right)$$

where

$$R_i=\{x\in \Bbb R\mid x<i\} \text{ (the left ray)}$$

Then

$$\bigcap_{i\in \Bbb N} X_i=\text{upper open half plane + lower open half plane}$$

Cleraly it's not connected.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another example of a family of nested, connected, non-compact sets that have a disconnected intersection, this time in a metric space.

Consider $\ell^2$, the vector space of real, square-summable sequences, with the usual norm $\|(x_n)\| = \sqrt{\sum x_n^2}$. Let $X$ be the unit sphere of $\ell^2$, specifically the set of points $(x_n)$ where $\|(x_n)\| = 1$. Further, for each $n \ge 1$, let
$$X_n = \{(x_m)_{m=1}^\infty \in X : x_2 = x_3 = \ldots = x_{n+1} = 0\}.$$
Then $X_n$ is (path) connected. It's a bit messy coming up with specific paths connecting any two points, but there is a trick you can use.

Suppose $(x_m) \in X_n \setminus \{-(e_m)\}$. Let $(e_m)$ be the point in $\ell^2$ such that $e_1 = 1$ and $e_m = 0$ for $m > 1$. For $K > 0$, consider the point
$$(y_m) = \frac{(x_m) + K(e_m)}{\|(x_m) + K(e_m)\|} \in X_n.$$
As $K \to \infty$, $(y_m) \to (e_m)$ continuously, proving that $(e_m)$ is in the same connected component as $(x_m)$.

If $(x_m) = -(e_m)$, then form a continuous path:
$$t \mapsto (\cos(t), 0 \ldots, 0, \sin(t), 0 \ldots) \quad t \in [0, \pi],$$
where the $\sin(t)$ term occurs in the $(n+2)$th coordinate, from $(e_m)$ to $-(e_m)$, completing the proof that $X_n$ is connected.

Now,
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty X_n = \{(x_m) \in X : x_m = 0 \; \forall m > 1\} = \{(e_m), -(e_m)\},$$
which is disconnected.