# Existence of disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ which are supersets of disjoint compact sets $A$ and $B$

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, connectedness

[Similar Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18192/disjoint-compact-sets-in-a-hausdorff-space-can-be-separated)

I am not familiar with Hausdorff spaces so I need to derive the above result using my existing knowledge which is:

In the context of metric spaces only, I already know that if two compact sets $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, then the distance between them is strictly positive.

Given this knowledge, is it possible to prove $A \subset U$ and $B \subset V$ for $U, V$ open and disjoint? How?

Comment: Metric spaces are Hausdorff... Learning what Hausdorff spaces are is worth your time.

Comment: For the metric space case the proof is very easy: simply define $U=\{x: d(x,A) <r\}$ and $V=\{x: d(x,B) <r\}$ where $0<r<d(A,B)$. The general case is slightly lengthier.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy If you want, you can put this as an answer and I will accept it. btw should it be $0 < r \leq \frac{d(A, B)}{2}$ ?

Comment: @ironX You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of a metric space you can just take $U=\{x:d(x,A) <r\}$ and $V=\{x:d(x,B) <r\}$ where $0 <r <\frac {d(A,B)} 2$.